# COALESCE default value with no double quote

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql table :

```
test_field (character varying(255)) | id
Hello  | 2
[null] | 3
```

My query is :

```
 SELECT
                    "id"
                    FROM
                        my_table
                    WHERE
                     string_to_array(COALESCE("test_field"::TEXT, 'null'), ',') && '{hello, null}'
                    ORDER BY "Date" DESC
                    LIMIT 200
```

I'm trying to convert NULL value into 'null' in string to match my search query.
Problem is it didn't grab the [null] values from '{hello, null}'

Then i tried this query :

```
select string_to_array(COALESCE("test_field"::TEXT, 'null'), ',') from my_table
```

And result is

```
{hello}
{"null"}
```

So i understand COALESCE or something else is adding double quote inside the array. But i don't want because the search will not work with this double quotes.

I tried to remove double quote with replace function but i don't succeed, any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `REPLACE` to replace `null` to `"null"` and `::TEXT[]` to cast our string into array as follows :

```
SELECT
"id"
FROM my_table
WHERE string_to_array(COALESCE("test_field"::TEXT, 'null'), ',') 
      && REPLACE('{Hello, null}', 'null' , '"null"')::TEXT[];
```

Or just search on `{Hello, "null"}` instead of `{hello, null}` if it is possible :

```
SELECT
"id"
FROM my_table
WHERE string_to_array(COALESCE("test_field"::TEXT, 'null'), ',') && '{Hello, "null"}'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/HrtvUhDx)

Comment: I can't change this part :/ the {hello, null} can't be modify

Comment: Can you check my edit